# pipeInput not creating record in State Store

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to pipe a txnMessage, and when I check if it was populated in the stateStore my test object comes back null. The point of this is I've written a class that will create a tombstone based on the topic, key, and stateStoreName so I want to assert that the object was in the state store, I'll run my class and then the test object will be null. Any thoughts?

```
txnTopic = utils.getProperty("myInputTopic");
// config, topology building

  public void testCleanKafkaKTable() throws IOException {
    String uri = "/Transactiontxn-1/1.xml";

    ConsumerRecordFactory<String, byte[]> input =
            new ConsumerRecordFactory<>(
                    Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.ByteArray().serializer());

    GenericRecord txn = testUtils.getTransaction("txn-1", (long) 1);
    String txnId = txn.get("MetadataUri").toString();
    byte[] byteArr = "This is my value.".getBytes();

    try {
      ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> txnMessage =
          input.create(txnTopic, txnId, byteArr);
      KeyValueStore<String, byte[]> stateStore =
          (KeyValueStore<String, byte[]>) testDriver.getStateStore(stateStoreName);

      // Doesn't populate stateStore
      testDriver.pipeInput(txnMessage);
      Object testObject = stateStore.get(uri);
      // testObject still null      assertTrue(testObject != null);
```

Thanks

Comment: Your assumption is basically correct. It seems your program is not doing what is support to do. I would recommend to set a breakpoint in your `Processor` to observe if it processed the input message correctly